# Convert float to float option

Tags: ocaml

How can I convert float to float option. Here is the function:

```
let variance (list_ : float list) : float option = 
if List.length list_ < 2 then None
else begin
    let average tmp_list = List.fold_left(+.) 0. tmp_list /. float(List.length tmp_list) in
    let square value = value *. value in
    let rec sum tmp_list =
        match tmp_list with
        | [] -> 0.0
        | head::tail -> square (head -. average tmp_list) +. sum tail
    in Some (sum list_ /. float(List.length list_))
end
```

I need `sum list_ /. float(List.length list_)` to return `float option` instead of `float` and I don't know how to do it. I thought if I return float in a float option function it would automatically return float option but I get the following error:

> Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected
>   of type float option

I have tried wrapping it around `Some` and failed. Can't seem to find anything on the internet.

EDIT: Added the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code runs, it just gives the wrong answer. That's because you `sum` function is incorrect : you should always use the average of the whole list, whereas you use the average from the current element onwards.

```
let variance l = 
  let sum l = List.fold_left (+.) 0. l in
  let average l = 
    match List.length l with
        0 -> None 
      | n -> Some (sum l /. float_of_int n) in
  match average l with 
      None -> None
    | Some m -> average (List.map (fun x -> (x -. m)**2.) l)
```